# WSO2 DSS Domain configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm running a WSO2 DSS 3.5.1 instance on a webserver but now i want to expose it to web using a domain address (like www.esb.com). The problem is that WSO2 can't resolve my external address, returning a 404 error.

I'm already try to modify the axis2.xml file as described on this site (https://www.yenlo.com/blog/creating-a-custom-url-for-wso2-esb-proxies-and-wso2-apis-wso2torial) but nothing change.

Can someone help me? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: After performing the changes in axis2.xml, do you get any issues while restarting the server, try restarting the server on debug mode and then check if you can capture any error logs

Comment: `WSO2 can't resolve my external address`  I don't think resolving the external address is so crucial. what returns 404? The data services? Are they even invoked? anything in the logs?